# How to make $_SESSION variable NOT be overwritten

Tags: php, session, mysqli, session-variables, overwrite

So with my website I have a problem that my $_SESSION variable is being overwritten when I don't want it to. Essentially how my website works is:

1. User enters their review using form input's.
2. Information they enter is stored in a new variable.
3. These variables are then stored in my mysqli database.
4. Then a new .php page is created (everytime the user makes a review) and copies a 'template.php' file which contains the basic layout of my website.
5. Then using header the user is redirected to the new .php file.
6. Then session starts and session variables are created which equal the new variable created in step 2.
7. The 'template.php' file has the basic layout of the webpage and also has the $_SESSION variables displayed on the page so the user can see their review.

The problem is when the user makes a new review all previous reviews have the same information as the new review because the $_SESSION variable has changed. How do I make it so that the information displayed on previous reviews doesn't change (and still is displayed) when a new review is created. 
Code for step 1-6 (didn't include establishing connection to mysql database):

```
       <p>Please leave blank any entries below that you don't know</p>
            <p>Artist:</p>
            <input type="text" name="artistbox">
            <p>Featured Artists:</p>
            <input type="text" name="featuresbox">
            <p>Title:</p>
            <input type="text" name="songbox">
            <p>Album:</p>
            <input type="text" name="albumbox">
            <p>Choose a genre:</p>
            <select name="genre"> 
                <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
                <option value="Hip-hop">Hip-hop</option>
                <option value="RnB">RnB</option>
                <option value="EDM">Electronic Dance Music</option>
                <option value="Jazz">Jazz</option>
                <option value="Blues">Blues</option>
                <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
                <option value="Punk-rock">Punk-rock</option>
                <option value="Reggae">Reggae</option>
                <option value="Classic">Classic</option>
                <option value="Funk">Funk</option>
                <option value="Soul">Soul</option>
            </select>
            <p>Rating:</p>
            <select name="rating">
                <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
                <option value="1.0">1.0</option>
                <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
                <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
                <option value="3.0">3.0</option>
                <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
                <option value="4.0">4.0</option>
                <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
                <option value="5.0">5.0</option>
            </select>
            <p>Comments (1000 character limit):</p>
            <textarea name="commentsbox" cols="60" rows="7"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">

$artistbox = $_POST['artistbox'];
$featuresbox = $_POST['featuresbox'];
$songbox = $_POST['songbox'];
$albumbox = $_POST['albumbox'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$commentsbox = $_POST['commentsbox'];
date_default_timezone_set('NZ');
$time = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

$queryartist = "INSERT INTO `artist` (`ArtistsName`)
          VALUES ('{$artistbox}')";
$queryfeatures = "INSERT INTO `features` (`Features`)
          VALUES ('{$featuresbox}')";
$querysong = "INSERT INTO `SongName` (`SongName`)
          VALUES ('{$songbox}')";
$queryalbum = "INSERT INTO `album` (`Album`)
          VALUES ('{$albumbox}')";
$querygenre = "INSERT INTO `genre` (`Genre`)
          VALUES ('{$genre}')";
$queryrating = "INSERT INTO `rating` (`Rating`)
          VALUES ('{$rating}')";
$querycomments = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`Comments`)
          VALUES ('{$commentsbox}')";
$querydate = "INSERT INTO `DateReviewed` (`DateReviewed`)
          VALUES ('{$time}')";

$conn->query($queryartist);
$conn->query($queryfeatures);
$conn->query($queryalbum);
$conn->query($querygenre);
$conn->query($queryrating);
$conn->query($querycomments);
$conn->query($querydate);

if ($conn->query($querysong) === TRUE) 
{
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
}   
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$querylink = "INSERT INTO `link` (`link`) VALUES ('{$link}')";
$conn->query($querylink);
$newpage = fopen("form_$last_id.php", "w+");
copy ('template.php', "form_$last_id.php");
header("location: form_$last_id.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION["artist"]=$artistbox;
$_SESSION["features"]=$featuresbox;
$_SESSION["album"]=$albumbox;
$_SESSION["genre"]=$genre;
$_SESSION["rating"]=$rating;
$_SESSION["comments"]=$commentsbox;
$_SESSION["songbox"]=$songbox;
$_SESSION["time"]=$time;
exit ();
```

Code for step 7 (extracts from the template.php file not all the code):

```
session_start();
$artist = $_SESSION["artist"];
$features = $_SESSION["features"];
$album = $_SESSION["album"];
$genre = $_SESSION["genre"];
$rating = $_SESSION["rating"];
$comments = $_SESSION["comments"];
$song = $_SESSION["songbox"];
$time = $_SESSION["time"];

<p> 
   <?php 
        echo '<b>', 'By: ', '</b>'. $artist . ' ft. ' . $features . 
        '</br>';
        echo '<i>' . $album . '</br>', '</br>', '</i>';
        echo '<b>', 'Genre: ', '</b>' . $genre . '</br>', '</br>';
        echo '<b>', 'Rating: ', '</b>' . $rating . '/5', '</br>', 
        '</br>';
        echo '<b>', 'Comments: ', '</b>', '</br>', '</br>' . 
        $comments;
   ?>    
</p>
```

Comment: use a multi dimensional array, so new key fore each review `$_SESSION[]["artist"]=$artistbox;` etc

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ok so how would I go about doing that. Would the new key be stored in my mysqli database?

Comment: Sweet so if I change $_SESSION["artist"] to $_SESSION[ ]["artist"]=$artistbox etc. at the end of the first block of code that will fix the solution. Would i need to change any of the code in Step 7 (bottom block of code). And would it be a 2 or 3 or 4 dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Organize each review under it's primary key in the session variable, you'll end up with a multi-dimensional array.

When a user writes a new review you already store it in your database. After doing so add the review to your session variable using it's pk. You will also need to store the song's primary key in the link table as well.

```
session_start();
$querylink = "INSERT INTO `link` (`link`) VALUES ('{$link}')";
$conn->query($querylink);

$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["artist"] = $artistbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["features"] = $featuresbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["album"] = $albumbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["genre"] = $genre;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["rating"] = $rating;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["comments"] = $commentsbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$conn->insert_id]["songbox"] = $time;
```

Consider changing your design approach, and store the song's id in the link table as well. When a user clicks a song, you can use the song_id to query your database and display all reviews for that song.

When a user is writes a review for a song, you will store the review in your database, including the $song_id, and add it to your session variable. Something like below.

```
session_start();
$querylink = "INSERT INTO `link` (`link`,`song_id`) VALUES ('{$link}','{$song_id}')";
$conn->query($querylink);

$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["artist"] = $artistbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["features"] = $featuresbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["album"] = $albumbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["genre"] = $genre;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["rating"] = $rating;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["comments"] = $commentsbox;
$_SESSION['reviews'][$song_id][$conn->insert_id]["songbox"] = $songbox;
```

Comment: Sweet. I already have an ID number for each table in my database. I.e. I have my database setup so that each table that has two columns. One called ID and another based on what the table is for (e.g. ArtistsName for artist table, Genre for genre table). Should I use this ID for the array. And when referencing the $_SESSION array later would I use $_SESSION['reviews']

Comment: You should have one table for reviews, with at least 3 columns e.g. 
review_id, song_id, review. Where 
review_id: primary key of the review
song_id: the song the user is reviewing
review: the actual review or message the user is leaving

Comment: So I make a new table in my database called reviews. Then I replace the code at the bottom of the first block of code i posted with the code you provided at the bottom of your answer. This will insert the $song_id into the table 'reviews' as a $_SESSION array named "artists", "features" etc. Where does $song_id come from? Also when referencing it in the new .php page would i use $_SESSION['artist'] to display the artist. Sorry for the ton of questions I am inexperienced with php.